# Why do we consider a non-inertial frame of reference for rotational motion but not for linear motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, centrifugal-force

When we consider a body rotating around a central point, we say that pseudoforce acting outwards in the non inertial frame of reference keeps the body at rest in the frame of reference.

If we consider a body to be moving in linear motion and a frame of reference that follows the body, the body is at rest with respect to the frame of reference, then there must be a pseudoforce acting on it in that frame of reference.

Why then do we only consider a pseudoforce in case of circular motion and not consider one in case of linear motion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Pseudoforces" such as centrifugal force only arise when you are using co-ordinates fixed in a non-inertial reference frame. In the case of a object rotating about an axis, a reference frame in which the object is at rest is non-inertial because the object (and hence also the reference frame) is accelerating.

If an object is moving in a straight line at a constant speed then a reference frame in which that object is at rest is an inertial reference frame and so no pseudoforces arise.

However, if an object is moving in a straight line but *not* at a constant speed then a reference frame in which that object is at rest is *not* an inertial reference frame and so pseudoforces will again arise if you are working in that reference frame. A typical example is an object on the floor of a lift that is accelerating with acceleration $a$. To account for the object being at rest in the lift we have to introduce a pseudoforce $ma$ that increases (or decreases) the apparent weight of the object.

Comment: In Newtonian physics. irl (e.g. GR), all pseudo forces are just gravitation.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is a vector quantity. Since the direction of the velocity vector is changing continuously in rotational motion, there is acceleration. Hence rotational motion is not an inertial frame of reference.